# CIFilter CISmoothLinearGradient crashing when passing color in Swift

Tags: swift, gradient, uicolor, cifilter

I'm trying to use the CISmoothLinearGradient in an iOS app, and it seems to not like the 2nd inputColor no matter what I put in, possibly because of the alpha parameter.

I've tried several other ways of setting up the CIFilter, but I used this to pinpoint where the issue was cropping up:

```
    let gradientFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISmoothLinearGradient")
    gradientFilter?.setDefaults()
    gradientFilter?.setValue([0, 0], forKey: "inputPoint0")
    gradientFilter?.setValue(inputPoint1Vector, forKey: "inputPoint1")
    gradientFilter?.setValue(UIColor.black, forKey: "inputColor0")
    gradientFilter?.setValue(UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), forKey: "inputColor1") // crash
```

The console states:
**-[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor alpha]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c4259830**

Originally I was using UIColor.white, but still it shows that UICachedDeviceWhiteColor error.

Comment: This actually works s an answer, but I'll leave it for you to work through as a learning exercise. The first two keys are `CIVectors` and the last two are `CIColors`. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISmoothLinearGradient

Comment: Ugh.. I missed that thank you. I didn't see they were CIColors, not UIColors.

Comment: Don't forget about the `CIVectors` too - your code doesn't look like they are. But I'm not sure that will fix the error you've posted because I'd have thought you'd get a different error.

Comment: The vectors are fine and inputColor0 works fine, but I can't get inputColor1 to work when I put in a CIColor. If I put in CIColor.black (or any color for inputColor1) my app crashed immediately. I wish I could share the message it gave, but it magically doesn't seem to be crashing it anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CIColor and CIVector will do the work in this case.

Replace the values of RGB and x,y according to your need

```
        var color1 = CIColor(red: 238/255, green: 97/255, blue: 35/255, alpha: 1)
        var color2 = CIColor(red: 246/255, green: 66/255, blue: 227/255, alpha: 1)

        let gradientFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISmoothLinearGradient")
        gradientFilter?.setDefaults()
        gradientFilter?.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0), forKey: "inputPoint0")
        gradientFilter?.setValue(CIVector(x: 200, y: 200), forKey: "inputPoint1")
        gradientFilter?.setValue(color1, forKey: "inputColor0")
        gradientFilter?.setValue(color2, forKey: "inputColor1")
```